# Why does the ball in this animation look chopped when it changes position?

Tags: animation, silverlight-4.0

Here is a link to the animation: http://www.microdivision.com/blog/Strange-Silverlight-Behavior

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="BouncingBall.MainPage"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="Bounce" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Ball">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-144" KeySpline="0,1,1,1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger>
            <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Bounce}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFCADFFF">
        <Ellipse x:Name="Ball" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="#FFF31D1D" Canvas.Top="190" Canvas.Left="0">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
    </Canvas>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: It looks perfect to me.  What browser are you experiencing the problem in?

Comment: I tried different browsers like IE8, Chrome 10, Firefox. i also asked another person to look at this page from his computer and he also noticed it. When the ball goes up and down, it will look litle flattened at the top and bottom.

Comment: Interesting that when i'm making a print screen of it it shows a full ball, maybe it has to do with the screen refresh?

Comment: @Shrage, the animation looks good on my end. When the ball hits the ground and then immediately bounces up there is a slight flicker on the bottom edge, but not on the top.

Comment: I added to the link above a slow motion video recording of my screen, and i have a high end monitor and computer (Windows 7 64Bit)

Comment: Sadly you may be better served to use a keyframe animation which include the intermediate points.  This will break the calculation of the path into pieces and may operate better for something as simple as a ball bouncing.  Try using the SpeedRatio property with your existing animation to slow it down as see how it handles a slower rate.

Comment: @Nissan so sometimes too simple could make things worse ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by SharpGIS at http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/223659.aspx enabling hardware acceleration solved the problem.

For HTML modify the Silverlight control to include the following param:

```
<param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the result of how Silverlight is adapting during playback.  On my machine the ball appears unchopped **most of the time** despite the fact that I have an older machine with hardly a good CPU/GPU.  Silverlight uses only CPU for rendering (except for 3D perspective operations when told to do so) and its time-based animation allows it to cut frames in order to adapt to the host client.  It is known for choppiness as a result.  Silverlight 5 promises GPU support.

Any reason you are using a spline to create the bounce instead of this?

```
<Storyboard x:Name="Bounce" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Ball">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-144">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Bounciness="0" Bounces="1"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

Comment: No particular reason for the spline the animation was  actually more complex, i simplified it for troubleshooting. even when i change it to use the built in bounce easing i still see a big flat ball. strange

Comment: but its strange that silverlight can handle much more complicated animation then a single ball bouncing, would you think that this simple animation is already overloading the CPU?

Comment: I wouldn't think it would, but since everything is on the UI Thread in Silverlight and the browser shares this it may be a problem that occurs differently in each browser engine.  I am not aware of how silverlight makes judgement calls around rendering internally.  Does it show the same result inside of FF, Chrome, IE, Safari?

Comment: Same result inside FF3, Chrome 10, IE8